# Как сделать браузерный тест для загрузки изображения Laravel?

Tags: laravel

```
function createPageAutn()
{
    $user = User::find(1);

   $this->actingAs($user)
         ->visit('/create')
         ->see('Add Image')
         ->attach('image.jpg',  __DIR__.'/uploads/image.jpg');
}
```

Выводит ошибку

```
Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: 
Expected selector, but <delimiter "/" at 44> found.
```

Вот обычный контроллер (обрезанный)

```
 $image = $request->file('image');

 $description = $request->input('description');

 $this->imageClass->add($image, $description);

 $this->imageClass->save();
```

Вот модель

```
 public function add($image, $description)
    {
        $fileName = $image->store('uploads');
        $this->image = $fileName;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->id_user = Auth::id();
    }

    public function updateImage($image, $imgOld)
    {
        //если пользователь загрузил новую картинку, то заменить её
        //если нет, то оставить старую
         if($image) {
            Storage::delete($imgOld->image);
            $fileName = $image->store('uploads');

            $this->image = $fileName;
         }                
    }
```